# Node.js: How can I determine whether a readable stream is at the end?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a function that accepts a readable stream as an argument. How can my function determine whether the given stream is already at the end?

Here's what I've ruled out already:

- Adding an event listener for the `end` event. If the stream is already at the end, it won't get run.
- Testing whether `stream.read()` returns null. Null could mean the stream is at the end, but it could also mean that the internal buffer is empty.

I'm using the latest API version (http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.12.7/api/stream.html). Is there any way to test whether the stream is at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for either

`readableStream.readable===false`

or

`readableStream._readableState.ended===true`

It's not documented but after checking the source, looks like these variable are set when the stream is ended.

Comment: Yecch—I was afraid the answer would be something that involves undocumented, underscore-prefixed properties.